# Magento 1.9.22 fresh install with sample data but the landing page not display

Tags: static-block, ce-1.9.2.2

the landing page (static block) of the category not working in Magento 1.9.22 fresh install with sample data, i just installed, but when i click on the category such as women, the related static block is not displayed.

Anyone know what is the issue?

update:

i just **disable all the cache and refreshed**, but it only displayed "abc"

```
  {{block type="cms/block" block_id="category-landingpage-women-mainblock"}}
  {{block type="cms/block" block_id="category-landingpage-women-linksblock"}}

  abc
```

Comment: i just add cms/block in system->permission solved the issues

Comment: so, it is resolved by add the block in the System -> Permissions -> Blocks?

Comment: yes ........................... may i delete this question?

Comment: I think its up to you :) You can delete it, or you can input your comment in Aswer box as the answer. Maybe there be other people who experienced the same thing and do not know the solution (although it seems that simple)